# Error while attempting to undo multiple revisions in Perforce P4V

Tags: perforce, p4v

I get this error while attempting to undo multiple revisions.

`c:\path\to\directory\...#4592,#head - no revision(s) above that revision`

I'm trying to get back to a specific revision, the one prior to #4592, undoing the 7 revisions that have happened since then.

My steps: I'm right-clicking the directory in question in P4V, selecting `Undo Changes`, then `Undo all changes from a selected point to the most recent version`, and putting in 4592 in the `Undo all changes beginning from` field. I hit submit, and I get the error.

Any idea what's up?

[Perforce undo error: "no revision(s) above that revision"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcbbP.png)

Comment: `#4592` is pretty big for a revision number -- did you mean to do this with a changelist number (which would be `@4592`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What ultimately worked was in the `Undo all changes beginning from` field, selecting `changelist` rather than `revision`.